# RailsAdmin hide field in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, rails-admin

I have custom configuration for `User` model:

```
rails_admin do
  list do
    field :name
    field :email
    field :company
  end

  edit do
    field :first_name
    field :last_name
    field :email
    field :password
    field :company
  end
end
```

And is there a way to hide company field (which is `has_many` relation) when using nested form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
edit do
  configure :companies do
    hide
  end
end
```

This **hides** companies field from `create` and `update` while still **showing** it when listing

Answer (score 1):

```
list do
    field :name
    field :email
    field :company do
      visible do
         false
      end
    end
end
```

Is that what you wanted? I did somenthing like this in a project that only the admin could use a field. Instead of "false" there was something like "bindings[:view]._current_user.admin?".

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe?

```
list do
  ....
  configure :company do
    hide
  end
end
```

Comment: As I know this will hide company only in list view. I need hide it when I am adding new user using Company view.